# How can a quasigroup have a division operation if a group has only one operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quasigroups

I'm teaching myself abstract algebra.

We can define a magma $\left(M,\cdot\right)$ as $a,b\in M\implies a\cdot b\in M$.
I get confused when we talk about quasigroups.
A group must satisfy all conditions of a magma, therefore it must be a set and a single binary operation.
And thus, a quasigroup must have a single binary operation.
However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Types_of_magma) says,

> Quasigroup: A magma where division is always possible.

Doesn't this imply that a quasigroup has two binary operations?
Or perhaps I am misunderstanding the meaning of division.

Does that mean that $a,b\in Q$ but not necessarily $a\div b\in Q$?

I think of the group of the set of integers with addition, $\left(\mathbb{Z},+\right)$.
If my assumption is correct, then this group satisfies the conditions of a quasigroup.
It satisfies $a,b\in G\implies a+b\in G$.
And it satisfies the condition that any element can divide another but not necessarily $a\div b\in G$.

Comment: A quasigroup is a magma in which for every $a$ and $b$, the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ always have unique solutions. This allows you to define a "derived operation"  of "right divide by $b$", where "$a\backslash b$" is shorthand for "the unique $x$ such that $ax=b$"; and a "left divide by $b$" where $b/ a$ is shorthand for "the unique $y$ such that $ya=b$". You can define a quasigroup in terms of those operations as well, just like the "multiplicative inverse" notion in a group is either shorthand for the unique solution of a certain equation, or a separate operation depending on your defs.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin's comment is exactly right. However, it's worth noting that there are substantive (if usually minor) differences between choices of language. For example, if we think of a group as a structure with only one binary operation, then the class of groups is **not equationally axiomatizable**. Does that matter? Well, it depends what you're looking at. Certainly paying attention to that sort of distinction leads to lots of interesting mathematics (in the setting of *universal algebra*) to the point that I've come to view the "correct" definition of a group as having $*,^{-1}$, and $e$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber So do I (and it is hinted at in the last sentence).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, +1. I mention your last point already in my introductory Algebra course. I believe this helps, in particular, in understanding the difference between homomorphisms of rings, and homomorphisms of rings with unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are teaching yourself *abstract* algebra, you have noticed that there are things you must learn not take for granted.  Literally you must subtract things that you thought you knew or that you associated with them.

Mathematicians have started with ideas born from the usual numbers and have looked if there was other instances of them.

But most teachers have a tendency to present certain facts or shortcuts or traditions as permanent and evident laws and they evaluate pupils on them when they are just consequences or special cases only valid in the context of what they teach.

Saying "addition, subtraction, multiplication, division are the four operations" is a good example. Even presenting them in this order is a choice.  Subtraction can be seen as just an inverse operation of addition or something more natural and direct than addition in a concrete context : if you break a twig that you found in the forest, you are subtracting a part from it.  Adding the part back together looks like a very abstract idea.
Division is usually presented as a separate operation but is it ?  Can you have two different division concepts for the same numbers with the same multiplication ?

You may define the same object or concept with different points of view.

As seen in comments, the division idea used in the definition you have seen is just one way to obtain or prescribe exclusive left and right divisors and prepare for the existence of neutral element.

Another look is the following:

In a quasigroup you can say that, at start, there is essentially one *ternary relation*, such that for each ordered couple of element, exactly one third element satisfies the relation.

```
 a * b = c
```

expresses this relation (as R(a,b,c) would), as

```
a = c / b
```

and

```
b = a \ c
```

would do as well.

In fact, each of these "operations" could be the unique operation of the quasigroup, having the others as right and left division.

Comment: This helped me a lot (and so did everyone's comments). Thank you, all! I understand that a group is usually defined with *multiplication*, which isn't necessarily the multiplication operation that I learned in second grade. But your answer reiterated that in a very easy-to-understand way, which led me to understand the idea of the *divisibility* property of a quasigroup.